# How to avoid Node.js's readline blows up Intellij's IDEA terminal?

Tags: node.js, macos, intellij-idea, puppeteer, readline

I have a simple NPM script using puppeteer to download a browser. The download callback function uses Node.js's readline showing the progress:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout});

await puppeteer
      .createBrowserFetcher(..)
      .download(puppeteer._preferredRevision, function (downloadBytes, totalBytes) {
        const percent = ..
        readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0)
        rl.write(`Downloading browser ${percent.toString().padStart(5)}%`)
      })
}
```

This works as expected in my Mac Terminal (TERM=xterm-256color) where a line like

```
Downloading browser   8%
```

is continuously redrawn (updated) to show the download progress. However, running the same Node.js script inside a IntelliJ's Terminal I'm getting an (almost) endless long string like

```
.. 51%Downloading browser   51%Downloading browser     51%Downloading browser     51%Downloading browser    51%Downloading browser ..
```

which eventually requires 100% CPU for updating that progress string. Needless to say that downloading takes endless time.

Is there a way to make readline work nicely in IntelliJ? Or can I change the default TERM in Intellij (apart from touching .profile and comrades)?

Some version pointers, just in case:

- IntelliJ: 2021.1
- Node: v15.2.1
- NPM: 7.10.0
- Mac: MacOS Catalina

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37687 looks related. You can check if the registry key is enabled in your case (it should be by default): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1933#focus=Comments-27-3141105.0-0

Comment: @Oksana - thx, yes - kind of similar. Key in IDEA registry is enabled. Not using a node.js terminal though. Just running npm within regular shell terminal, i.e. running npm run .. as well as other shell commands (cd, ls, ps and so on).